# How to process a vector of lists in R?

Tags: r

I have an R dataset where DimB is comprised of lists, for example:

```
DimA | DimB  | DimNew
Aa    [1,2,3]   Yes
Ab    [4,5,6]   
Ac    [1,7,8]   Yes
```

I would like to iterate each list in DimB, and where the list in DimB contains 1, return "Yes" otherwise return "No".

I have tried the following, but not such luck

> dataset <- mutate(dataset, DimNew = if(dataset$DimB %in% 1){"Yes"})

Comment: could you please paste the `dput(your_data)` here. The list seems to be a python list and not a valid R object. Probably its a string etc. Just paste the results of `dput`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    library(dplyr)
    set.seed(0)
    l=(lapply(1:5,function(x){sample(10,3)}))
    dataset <- data.frame(dimB=I(l))
    dataset <- dataset %>% mutate(DimNew = lapply(dimB, function(x) { ifelse(1 %in% x,"Yes","")}))
    dataset
    #>      dimB DimNew
    #> 1 9, 4, 7       
    #> 2 1, 2, 5    Yes
    #> 3 7, 2, 3       
    #> 4 3, 1, 5    Yes
    #> 5 5, 6, 9

<sup>Created on 2020-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the desired result:

```
> mydf
  DimA    DimB
1   Aa 1, 2, 3
2   Ab 4, 5, 6
3   Ac 1, 7, 8

find.element <- function(list1){check <- if(1 %in% unlist(list1)) "Yes" else ""}
mydf$DimNew <-mapply(find.element, mydf$DimB)
mydf

  DimA    DimB DimNew
1   Aa 1, 2, 3    Yes
2   Ab 4, 5, 6       
3   Ac 1, 7, 8    Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the code below?

```
dataset$DimNew <- sapply(dataset$DimB,function(x) ifelse(1 %in% x,"Yes","No"))
```